# How to groupBy and count the pivot table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, group-by, count, pivot-table

I have three tables,

```
     User                   cities             user_cities

id  name    title           id   name        user_id   city_id
1    aaa   designer         1   cityA          2         1
2    bbb   developer        2   cityB          2         2
3    ccc   designer         3   cityC          1         2
                                               1         1
                                               2         3
                                               3         2
```

After joining and querying the database my result is,

```
data: {
   0: {
      id: 1
      name: aaa,
      title: designer,
      cities :[
         0: {
            id: 1,
            name: cityA
          }
          1: {
            id: 2,
            name: cityB
          }
          2: {
            id: 3,
            name: cityC
          }
        ]
    },
    1: {
      id: 2
      name: bbb,
      title: developer,
      cities :[
         0: {
            id: 1,
            name: cityA
          }
          1: {
            id: 2,
            name: cityB
          }
        ]
    }
    1: {
      id: 3
      name: ccc,
      title: designer,
      cities :[
          0: {
            id: 2,
            name: cityB
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

Everything is fine until here. But i want to `groupBy` by cities and take count.

If i filter by `title=designer` the filtered data will display and i want to make group by cities and take count of it.

So my final result will be,

```
cityA = 1 counts
cityC = 2 counts
```

Help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Can somebody help please?

Comment: Show me your query code.

Comment: Have you heard about models and relations?

Answer (score -1):

You might use the [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) to eager load the relationship counts.

I assume you already have the cities relationship defined in the User.php model:

```
class User
{
    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(City::class);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
$users = User::withCount('cities')->get();
```

I think the results are gonna be:

```
data: {
   0: {
      id: 1
      name: aaa,
      title: designer,
      cities_count: 3
    },
    1: {
      id: 2
      name: bbb,
      title: developer,
    cities_count: 2

    }
    1: {
      id: 3
      name: ccc,
      title: designer,
      cities_count: 1
    }
}
```

An alternative could be using lazy eager loading:

```
$users = User::all()->loadCount('cities');
```